# Wrong range in if (mathematic function)

Tags: c, console-application

Here is my code:

```
dx = (to - from) / n;
x = from - dx;

printf("\n\n          X           math.h           szereg      i  abortReason\n\n");

while(x <= to) {
    x += dx;

    if(x > -1. && x <= 1.) {
        printf("%11lf %16lf %16lf", x, log(1 + x), myFunc(x, epsilon, m, &abort));
        printf(" %7d  %s\n", abort, getAbortReason(abort, &m));
    } else {
        notInScope++;
    }
}
```

I made if condition becouse my mathematic function has scope (-1 < x <= 1) but in the end I'm getting this:

[image]

How to make my range works correctly? Its one of the stupid questions :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how floating point works - it has finite resolution, and your `dx` value is not exactly representable.

You can change your loop from:

```
while(x <= to) {
    x += dx;

    // ...
}
```

to:

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
{
    x = from + (double)i * dx;

    // ...
}
```

This ensures that you get the correct range and the correct number of increments, and it also minimises rounding errors.

Comment: but range (-5, 5) is not always integer.

Comment: OK - you can still use this approach, but you'll need to calculate the required number of steps prior to the loop, then use an integer index combined with an appropriate offset and scale factor.

Comment: The loop using i needs to go from 0 to n inclusive and `x = from + i * dx`

Comment: @JeremyP: yes, thanks, I just noticed that the OP already has the no of steps as `n` -- answer updated.

Comment: @PaulR There was a typo in my comment as originally written

Comment: @Davgranded: note that the `for` loop is `for (i = 0; i <= n; ++i)` (i.e. `<= n`, not `< n`).

Answer (score 1):

When you need to use a range defined by floating point numbers and use an increment that is a floating point number, you are unlikely to get the precise number of increments. However, if you use an integer to control the number of increments, you will be able to control it.

Say you have:

```
double start = <some number>;
double end = <some number>;
int numIncrements = 10;
double delta = (end-start)/numIncrements;
```

The loop:

```
for ( double iter = start; iter <= end; iter += delta )
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

is less precise than:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= numIncrements; ++i  )
{
   double iter = start + i*delta;
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm using your last loop but it still doesn't work. Here is my full code. Come information are in Polish but I think that you will understand all. http://ideone.com/dDkpMB

Comment: The code looks correct to me. I am not sure what you expect the output to be. You haven't provided any input. `stdin` is empty at the posted link.

Comment: Input: 
-5
5
50
0.00001
50
On output should be some rows with X bigger then -1 and smaller or equal 1. But now it is FROM -1 and it doesnt contain 1

Answer (score 0):

Change `while(x <= to)` ---> `while(x <= (to+dx/2)` to provide ample margin with `x` due to the subtle floating point inaccuracies.

Answer (score -2):

It started to work in Visual Studio (the problem was in CodeBlox)